# Node.js: Why am I required to set my environment variables every time I want to run Nodemon?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, nodemon

For some reason, despite having:

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

in my environment variables (I double checked - it's in my User PATH variable), I'm unable to run nodemon directly without getting the standard 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command error.

When I installed nodemon, I ran the following:

```
> npm install -g nodemon
```

Currently, in order to use nodemon, I'm required to run the following:

```
> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm
> nodemon
```

After re-setting the path, I can run nodemon again - that is - until I close the command prompt, at which point I need to run "set PATH" all over again.

To re-iterate, the path is *always* there in my environment variables, so I have no idea why I need to set it each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

It turns out that there was a space directly before my npm user environment variable.  For example, the PATH variable looked like this:

```
C:\path1;C:\path2; C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Note the space after the second path.  After removing this space, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you checked the path inside your command window prior to setting the path? How do you launch the command window?

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed the PATH variables directly in the command window.  I've run cmd.exe in Administrator mode just to make sure that it's not a permissions problem, but that doesn't solve the problem either.